# How can add External File to Project Resources?

Tags: ios4, xcode4.2

I have no any basic idea about xCode 4.2 for iOS 5, I just want to add one external file to resources but when i drag and drop any file to resources I see the one question mark '?' or 'A' behind the file name, Can you please tell me why this kind of things are occur ?

This is really basic question but i am confuse...

Please check this Image :)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the version control status of your project files.

```
A - A file just added to version control
M - A file that is in version control but has some changes since the last check in.
? - Is a file that is not being tracked or ignored.
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello Friends i got solution,

```
   After drag and drop file i just commit that files in version control and now i can successfully track that files :)
```

Thanks,